# Is it possible to specify a kafka topic in a Kafka Connect config?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Right now my Connect config writes its messages to a topic by the same name as the database table it's reading. Is it possible to specify the exact topic I want to write to instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a RegexRouter - https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/regexrouter.html

```
"transforms":"rename",
"transforms.rename.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
"transforms.rename.regex":".*",
"transforms.rename.replacement":"some-other-name"
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems obvious after reading its docs, but I never would have guessed what it does by the name alone.